# graphviz dot: how to change the orientation of a self pointing arrow?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm working on DOT with graphivz, I currently have this code:

```
    digraph {
    q0 -> q0[label="a"];
    q0 -> q1[label="b"];
    q1 -> q2[label="a"];
    q1 -> q1[label="b"];
    q2 -> q2[label="a"];
    q2 -> q0[label="b"];
    { rank=same; q0, q1 }
    q0[shape=circle];
    q1[shape=circle];
    q2[shape=circle, peripheries=2];
}
```

When rendering the graph I get:

[image: this]:

Would it be possible to change the q0 -> q0 arrow so that it appears on top of the node or to its left so that it doesn't overlap with the q0 -> q1 edge?

Comment: One possibility is to specify port directions: `q0:w -> q0` would force the loop to be on the left side of the node, for example.